# Objective C init methods shared between parent and child

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have a parent init method like so:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(int)val name:(NSString *)n 
{
    value = val;
    name = n;
}
```

and a child class with an init like so:

```
- (id)initWithAge:(int)a
{
    age = a;
}
```

Is there a way to do the following:

```
[Child initWithAge:10 value:12 name:@"Sam"];
```

where the age will go to the child init method and the "value" and "name" go to the parent method? Or does every child have to expect all arguments it expects and pass it to the parent using [super init]??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithAge:(int)a value:(int)val name:(NSString *)n
{
    self = [super initWithValue:val name:n];
    if(self)
    {
        age = a;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Child`, you would have to declare `initWithAge: value: name:`. Nothing will "go to the parent" method explicitly without some work on your part.

You would declare amethod in Child:

```
-(id)initWithAge:(int)age value:(iint)value name:(NSString*)name {
    if ( (self = [super initWithValue:value name:name]) ) {
        _age = age; // assuming you an ivar '_age'
    }
     return self;
}
```

You can pass certain things on to the super class, but only what it is expecting, nothing will create methods for you.

Have read on [inheritance](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance) and [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), and it important to understand what [self](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html) is.